# Como deixar a janela com fundo transparente no Kivy

Tags: python-3.x, kivy

Olá, eu estou tentando fazer um programa que crie uma janela sem bordas e com o fundo transparente.

A primeira parte já consegui:

```
Window.borderless = True
```

Mas ainda não consegui deixar o fundo transparente. Alguém sabe como fazer isso?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vitor utiliza essa função de exemplo:

```
from kivy.config import Config

Config.set('graphics', 'position', 'custom')

Config.set('graphics', 'fullscreen', 'fake')

Config.set('graphics', 'top', '0')

Config.set('graphics', 'left', '0')

Config.set('graphics', 'resizable',  True)

from kivy.app import App

from kivy.uix.label import Label

from kivy.core.window import Window

Window.size = (1000, 500)

from kivy.uix.widget import Widget

from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput

from kivy.uix.button import Button

from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout

from kivy.graphics import Color, Ellipse, Line,Rectangle

from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen

from kivy.uix.relativelayout import RelativeLayout

from kivy.uix.image import Image

import win32gui

import win32con

import win32api,pywintypes

import win32gui

import win32con

import win32api,pywintypes

class Program(App):

    def on_start(self):

        hwnd = win32gui.FindWindow(None, "pencere")

        win32gui.SetWindowLong(hwnd, win32con.GWL_EXSTYLE,win32gui.GetWindowLong(hwnd,win32con.GWL_EXSTYLE) | win32con.WS_EX_LAYERED | win32con.WS_CHILD | win32con.WS_EX_TRANSPARENT |win32con.WS_EX_TOPMOST)

        win32gui.SetLayeredWindowAttributes(hwnd, win32api.RGB(255, 0, 128),40, win32con.LWA_ALPHA)

    def build(self):

        sm = ScreenManager()

        duzen = FloatLayout()

        screen = Screen(name='deneme ekran 1')

        self.title = "pencere"

        yazi = Label(text = self.title,pos=(10,10),size=(100,35),size_hint=(None,None),halign="center",bold=True,color=(1,1,1,1))

        buton = Button(text="",size_hint=(None,None),size=(26,26))

        buton.pos = (0,0)

        buton.background_normal = "minimize.png"

        buton.background_down = "minimize.png"

        with Window.canvas:

            Color(0,1,0,1)

            Rectangle(pos=(10, 10), size=(100, 40))

            duzen.add_widget(yazi)

        return duzen

Program().run()
```

Usei isso quando comecei, retirei isso do reddit.

Segue referência:
[Link](https://www.reddit.com/r/kivy/comments/c86hvr/how_do_i_make_transparent_the_kivy_window/)

Comment: Vou ver se consigo fazer alguma coisa coisa com isso... De qualquer forma, obrigado pela ajuda!